# How do you make new a column from keyword?

Tags: openrefine

Beginner's question: I have a column with free text sentences, and I'm trying to draw a particular keyword out of this column and create a new column out of that particular keyword. How would I go about doing that? A GREL command?

Answer (score 0):

As usual there are several options for this.

### Facets & Filtering

1. You could use a [Word facet](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/facets#word-facet) or [Text filter](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/facets#text-filter) to **filter** rows containing your keyword.
2. Then with the filter in place [add a new column](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) and enter the string "YourKeyword" (or whatever text you like) as value for the new column.

### GREL

1. [Add a new column](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) based on the column that contains the free text sentences.
2. Use either [value.find("YourKeyword")[0]](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#finds-sub-or-p) or [value.contains("YourKeyword")](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#containss-sub-or-p) as GREL expression.

Note that `find` will directly place the found keyword into the new column, whereas `contains` will add a boolean marker (`true` or `false`) indicating whether the keyword is present or not.

Beware that you might have to tweak the keyword searching based on the properties of your free text to avoid matching substrings. Meaning that "soft" will also match "software". Depending on your keyword and text properties you might want to have a look into [regular expressions](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/expressions#grel-supported-regex). Regular expressions are supported in the mentioned GREL functions and in the above mentioned text filter.

Comment: Thanks! if I were trying to pull out the keyword "soft" from a free text field and put that in a new column but also had the use of the word "software" in this field, what GREL expression would I use?

Comment: The GREL functions value and contains support regular expressions. With regular expressions you can define a word boundary `\b` like `/soft\b/` to avoid matching `software` with the needle `soft`.

Comment: If I'm making a new colum based on that, would it be value.find(/soft\b/)[0] ?

Comment: Yes, just try it out in the "Add new column" dialog. OpenRefine provides you with a preview of your action. Depending on your keyword you might use `/\bsoft\b/` to avoid matching keywords like Micro**soft**.